# Extract only the first occurence of the search string and ignore everything after /

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex and want to display all the folders that contain the string name but ignore the characters or inner directories after "/"

Using regex only

```
(*spark?/)
```

Below are the set of directories:

> /app-logs/spark/logs/application_15262_85484
>
> /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_36456456/spark
>
> /app-logs/spark/logs
>
> /app-logs/spark
>
> /apps/spark/warehouse

My result should be:

> /app-logs/spark
>
> /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_36456456/spark
>
> /app-logs/spark
>
> /apps/spark

Comment: Try `(.*spark/?)`

Comment: Same result no change

Comment: Please define "same result". What's going wrong and how do you display? Your regex btw. is wrong as `*` has to follow something (like a `.`). Also the `?` is wrong as `spark?`matches "spar" as well as "spark".

Answer (score 1):

The expression we might be looking for here, would be:

```
(spark)\/?.*
```

which we would replace it with our first capturing group, `$1`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cj2jsY/1/)

#### Test

```js
const regex = /(spark)\/?.*/gm;
const str = `/app-logs/spark/logs/application_15262_85484
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_36456456/spark
/app-logs/spark/logs
/app-logs/spark
/apps/spark/warehouse`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `(*spark?/)` is not valid because before the quantifier `*` there is a an opening parenthesis for the capturing group which is not valid. The questionmark after the k means that the character `k` is optional.

You could use a repeating pattern to match a forward slash followed by matching not a forward slash, then match `/spark`

```
^(?:/[^/\n]+)+/spark
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `/[^/\n]+` Match `/`, then match 1+ times not `/` or a newline
- `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `/spark` Match `/spark`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vWAR9s/1)